# Evaluating using Contour Integration

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Another revision question I need a bit of help with, sorry guys!

By choosing an appropriate contour, evaluate the following integral;

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{iz}}{(z-i)^2}$$

Every time I attempt this question, I get the denominator to equal 0 somehow. I'm sure there must be a smarter way to manipulate the denominator into getting the **z** not equal to **i**, but I'm stuck how to at the moment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: your integrand function is a complex non-real one, yet your integral is, apparently, a real one. It looks like you already have a given contour, unless you meant something else.

Comment: That's how the question was worded in the revision notes

Comment: That's fine, but I expect anyone posting a question here to understand *at least* what is being asked. Notes, books can have mistakes, or maybe it is just something you worked on. I can't say.

Comment: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/residues_1996/residue.pdf This is an application of the residue theorem.

Comment: Your example looks a lot like the complex integral one sees when trying to solve *real integrals* of the form $\;\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin x}{(x^2+1)^2}\;$ and then one chooses a contour on the upper half plane, and looks at the residues there and etc. Yours looks different...

Comment: @FaraadArmwood What do you want to look at in that paper?

Comment: Try integrating along the contour $[-R,R]$ along the real axis and then in a semi-circle from $R$ to $-R$ in the upper half-plane. Notice that $iz = ix - y$ has negative real part in the upper half-plane so $e^{iz}$ is bounded there and you can show that the integral over the semi-circle vanishes as $R\to\infty$. The residue theorem is then all you need to evaluate the integral.

Comment: @DonAntonio, I was really hoping that the OP meant $z - 1$, and the paper has some residue theorem calculations.

Comment: to be honest, the lecturer who wrote it often makes mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a large value of $R\in\mathbb{R}^+$, consider the countour $\gamma_R$ made by a segment $S_R$ between $-R$ and $R$ and the semicircle $\Gamma_R$ in the upper half-plane joining $R$ with $-R$ (let all the path be counter-clockwise oriented). By the residue theorem,
$$\oint_{\gamma_R}\frac{e^{iz}}{(z-i)^2}\,dz = 2\pi i\cdot\text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{iz}}{(z-i)^2},z=i\right)=2\pi i\cdot \frac{i}{e}=\color{red}{-\frac{2\pi}{e}}$$
and you just need to prove that
$$ \lim_{R\to +\infty}\int_{\Gamma_R}\frac{e^{iz}}{(z-i)^2}\,dz = 0.$$